# UIButton don't response when cpu is high

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, uibutton

i've created a UIButton in the interface builder, and added an action to it.

I'm using camera with OpenCV and when the CPU is high i tap on the button and nothing happened.

The OpenCVCamera has a delegate method that call's in more then 20 fps. for each frame I'm doing filters and more on the frame.

how can i solve it ?

Comment: So you're doing lots of processing on the main thread? Show the code.

Comment: what can i send you ? the button is in the .xib file and i can't reveal the processing algorithms

Comment: Yes it was because the main thread was busy

Answer (score 0):

You should perform all heavy computations in other worker threads (not in a main thread)